# unauthorised for getting kubectl api-versions

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private

I am trying to install ICP version 3 where the setup is automated via ansible to setup a kubernetes cluster. However the setup keeps failing with :

```
 kubectl api-versions
error: Couldn't get available api versions from server: Unauthorized
```

Any pointers how can this be debugged?

Comment: which user/servcie account are you using to access the API server? it needs to have permissions

Comment: I am using root.

Comment: there is not root user in kubernetes :)

Comment: How to know which user has access ? /root/.kube/config had user admin. How do I use that user? I tried `su - admin` but its not a unix user.

Comment: kubernetes does not use unix users , you need to copy the admin kubeconfig into your /root/.kube/config  and make sure it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Unauthorized usually means you haven’t logged into the cluster with cloudctl or using the ‘Configure Client’ option in the UI to set the kubectl context